# What is this symbol in the definition of the homotopy extension property?

Tags: algebraic-topology, notation, definition, homotopy-theory

[image]

What does the symbol inside the red circle represent?  Is it just some sort of inclusion mapping?

Comment: The inclusion map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the subset inclusion map.